# How does angular2 decide whether to update or recreate a component?

Tags: angular

Assuming I have an Angular2 component which has some input properties, like

```
@Component(...)
class ChildComponent {
   @Input() input1: string;
   @Input() input2: number;
   internalState: any;
}
```

which is used in another component, probably even in a list, like:

```
<li *ngFor="#item of items">
  <child-component [input1]="item.a" [input2]="item.b">
  </child-component>
</li>
```

where the input parameters get mutated:

How does Angular2 decide if a child-component should be updated (input variables set to new values and `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook called) or whether it should be destroyed and a new component created? And are there any possibilites to influence the behavior?

The reason why I'm asking is because if the component has any internal state besides the input parameters then it would make a difference if it's updated or recreated. In the updated case it would keep the old internal state (e.g. if something is collapsed, if the user entered something), in the recreated case we would get a fresh initialized component with default state.

Depending on the component I would for sure sometimes require the first and sometimes the other approach.

If the component has some complex initialization logic and does not store user data then I think it would be easier to treat the inputs as immutable and only initalize the component once in ngOnInit instead of thinking what need to be done on `ngOnChanges`.

The question becomes even trickier when the there is a list of child components like in the given example. If the service that provides me the list now inserts a new item in the middle of the list and gives me an updated list (could be either a mutated or a new version of an immutable list) - how does angular2 know that I want a new item to be created in the middle of the list instead of updating the existing items with new values and creating a new item at the end? The latter approach would shift the internal state of a prior existing item to the new item and a prior existing items input data would get assigned to the new created component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [NgFor docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html):

> Angular uses object identity to track insertions and deletions within the iterator and reproduce those changes in the DOM. This has important implications for animations and any stateful controls (such as `<input>` elements which accept user input) that are present. Inserted rows can be animated in, deleted rows can be animated out, and **unchanged rows retain any unsaved state** such as user input.

There are some additional details in the doc that you might want to read.

Comment: Thanks, I looked through the developer guides chapters but not in the API doc for NgFor, and so have not found that.Looks reasonable and easily comprehensible (just use a single instance of a mutable object for each item in a container). Although it's interesting that it will break if only immutable data structures are used (like it's currently in fashion in the React ecosystem). Have you an idea about customization options around that? The NgFor doc mentions an up-to-now undocumented IterableDiffers parameter, that sounds like it could help?

Comment: @Matthias247, sorry, no ideas.  I've only started learning A2 recently, and I avoid looking at A2 source code as much as possible.